# Angular Reactive Form: - Fill Input dynamically in Dynamic rows

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on a Register module where User can add multiple channels, Like google, yahoo, outlook and custom.

**Questions:-**

1. OnSelection of Custom Url field would be empty and in case of other domain url field would pre filled.
2. If you select custom in domains then URl field needs to be blank and editable.
3. If I click on add more then form needs to be blank same like when page is getting load.

I have created Dummy form at https://angular-db4rzu.stackblitz.io. Looking for help.

Comment: On point 3, I am referring form for added column.

Comment: code is available @ https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-db4rzu You can fork and give a try. Thanks for quick reach out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a serious loop occurring in your project with the way you are subscribing to form changes, and then updating `FormControl` values based on the emit.

Essentially, you would change the value in the form, it would trigger `scmTypeCheck()` via the `valueChanges` subscription, which would set new values, then emit another change via `valueChanges` and trigger `scmTypeCheck()` again and again and again...

Then clicking `Add More Row` made it worse because the loop is growing exponentially, eventually exceeding the call stack limits.

> In my Stackblitz example I replaced your `valueChanges` subscription with `selectionChange` event on your `mat-select`... this ensures there is no loop and your `FormControl` values are only updated once.

I also replaced your entire `scmTypeCheck()` logic with the following.

```
setDomainName(i, value) {
  //get the index of the selected value in the scmDummyStructure to use for default values
  const index = this.scmDummyStructure.findIndex(x => x.type === value);
  //get the url control to set state and default on user change
  const urlControl = this.scmForm.get('scmDatas')['controls'][i].get('url');

  //set default value
  urlControl.setValue(this.scmDummyStructure[index].url);

  //if custom type enable and clear any existing value if field not pristine else disable
  if (value === 'custom') {
    if (!urlControl.pristine && urlControl.value != '') {
      urlControl.setValue('');
      urlControl.enable();
    }else{
      urlControl.enable();
    }
  } else {
    urlControl.disable();
  }
}
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7bjj6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please see revised stackblitz, specifically this line `console.log(this.scmForm.getRawValue())` in your `onSubmit()`... you need to use `getRawValue()` to get the values of the disabled `FormControl(s)`